# Difficulty clicking into textbox after applying css

Tags: html, css

This seems like a simple thing but I can't figure out what is causing it.

UPDATE: Here is a fiddle where I have replicated the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/X374V/1/

I have a simple text input in a form:

```
<input type="text" name="commentor" id="commentor"  />
```

with the style:

```
#commentor {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    height:25px;
    width:160px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#000;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
```

In order to click into the text box to type, i have to click at the very top edge of the box, clicking in the middle is missing it somehow. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: It work normal on my machine, do you have some jsfiddle?

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/X374V/

Comment: Well that's weird. I'll plug some of the other elements into the fiddle and see if i can recreate the problem there.

Comment: here is a fiddle with the problem http://jsfiddle.net/X374V/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it. Your div was covering the input.

```
#commentorName {
    color: #33CCCC;
    display: inline;
    font-family: futuraCondensed;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle with it working.

I changed the commentor `div` to a `span`.

http://jsfiddle.net/X374V/3/

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-left to the label:

```
#commentorName {
    position:relative;
    top:8px;
    font-family:futuraCondensed;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#33cccc;
    margin-left: 168px;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/harveyramer/Zp9D3/